# Implement self-modification in the fork()

Tags: linux, fork, self-modifying

In fork, the parent and child share the code, so if I modify the code content in the child (for example, by self-modifying), can the parent execute the modified content when it reaches the corresponding part?

Comment: The child receives a copy of the parents environment at the time `fork()` is called. Subject to a few exceptions, that is where the sharing of the environment ends. If changes are made in the child after `fork()` those changes won't be seen by the parent. You will need to show what you mean by "self-modifying" before any specific answer can be given.

Comment: This *can* be done if you use threads instead of processes (i.e. `pthread_create` instead of `fork`), as threads do share their memory.  On some platforms it may require special handling as instruction caches may not be coherent between cores, so the parent may have to take steps to flush its cache before it can reliably execute the modified code.

Comment: At low level the code pages are shared btw father and child as long as they are not modified (Copy-On-Write = COW mechanism). Once you modify one of them, it is copied in a new memory area and no longer shared btw both processes.